# Nested for loop to create 2 HTML rows every 3 items and wrap every 2 rows with an outer HTML wrapper

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So basically I am building a wordpress gallery, I need to have the images output into 2 rows, each row is 3 images across so essentially I am just splitting the output every 3..

I have that functionality working with a for loop using the modulus operator, what I need is that every 2 rows I need to have them wrapped in an outer HTML container

```
<div class="wrappy">
```

but I cant seem to get this quite right having worked on it most of yesterday, Im not that great at PHP but I understand enough to get by so any help at all would be great... I am using wordpress advanced custom fields for storing the images etc so you can ignore that part, the magic Im working on starts at

`<div class="wrappy">`

```
                <?php

                $rows = get_field('staff_slides', 'options');
                $countmax = count($rows) - 1;

                //echo $row_count; 

                $ender = "";
                $mainEnder = "";
                $outer_wrapper = "";

                if( have_rows('staff_slides', 'options') ):

                    // loop through the rows of data
                    while ( have_rows('staff_slides', 'options') ) : the_row();

                        $image_id = get_sub_field('slide_image', 'options');

                        $staff_members_name = get_sub_field('staff_members_name', 'options');

                        $staff_members_position = get_sub_field('staff_members_position', 'options');

                        $staff_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id , 'homepage-staff');


                ?>






                                <?php 


                    echo '<div class="wrappy">';


                                    echo '<div class="row">'; 

                                        if( $ender != "script-ended" )  {

                                            for( $i=0; $i <= $countmax; ) 
                                            { 

                                ?>

                                    <div class="staff-img c3">
                                        <div class="staff-caption">
                                            <h3><?php echo $rows[$i]['staff_members_name']; ?></h3>
                                                <span></span>
                                            <h4><?php echo $rows[$i]['staff_members_position']; ?></h4>
                                        </div>
                                            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( $rows[$i]['slide_image'], 'homepage-staff')[0]; ?>">
                                    </div>

                                <?php
                                        if( $i % 3 == 2 )  
                                        {


                                                echo '</div><div class="row">';
                                            }

                                        if( $i == $countmax ) 
                                        {
                                                $ender = "script-ended";                
                                            }


                                        if( $i == 6){


                                            $outer_wrapper = "set";

                                        }   





                                        $i++;

                                        }
                                    }

                                ?>

                <?php 

                if( $outer_wrapper == "set" ){

                    echo '</div><div class="wrappy">';

                }


                ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function to split the array in smaller arrays.
I'm not familiar with the ACF functions but you can do something like:

```
<div class="wrappy">
  <?php
  if( have_rows('staff_slides', 'options') ) :
  $slides = array_chunk(get_field('staff_slides', 'options'), 3);
    foreach ($slides as $slides_row) :
      ?>
      <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($slides_row as $slide_element) : the_row(); ?>
        <div class="staff-img c3">
          <div class="staff-caption">
            <h3><?php the_sub_field('staff_members_name', 'options'); ?></h3>
            <span></span>
            <h4><?php the_sub_field('staff_members_position', 'options'); ?></h4>
          </div>
          <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_sub_field('slide_image', 'options'), 'homepage-staff')[0]; ?>">
        </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; else : ?>
    No slides do to show
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This way you create a multidimensional array, divided in chunks of 3 elements, and iterate throught it.